# When to use {loadMaps: true} setting in gulp sourcemaps initialization?

Tags: gulp-sourcemaps

I am trying to find out if I need to use option of {loadMaps: true} in initialization. Help isn't clear about when and why you would need this option: https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#load-existing-source-maps

I'm running gulp watch task which builds my project on any file changes without this option and it is overwriting source maps with new changes. Right now my project is small so I am not sure if this has visible performance impact in large projects and it is recommended to set it to true.